# How to delay rendering of LoadingRoute / LoadingTemplate in Emberjs 1.0

Tags: ember.js

With the [loadingRoute feature](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_using-code-loadingroute-code-to-display-ui-while-the-router-is-loading) we have a nice way of showing loading indicators in Ember.js apps.
But what if you have very short loading times usually? The page transitions would get too noisy with flickering loading indicators. Therefore I think it is better to delay the actual rendering of the loading layer until a certain threshold is exceeded.
There are countless ways to do this but what is the nicest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is:

```
App.LoadingRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  deactivate: function() {
    var timer = this.get('timer');
    if (timer)
      Em.run.cancel(timer);
  },

  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    var self = this;
    // Only render the loading indicator after 0.5s
    var timer = Em.run.later(this, function() {
      self.render('loading')
    }, 500);
    this.set('timer', timer);
  }
});
```

It cancels the render if the promises are resolved before the threshold is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

One nice way I can think of to delay the `LoadingRoute` would be to delay the rendering of the template by using [`Ember.run.later`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later) which works as a `setTimeout` but much safer by running inside the runloop.

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.render();
    }, 1000); // put here the treshold you might find appropriate in ms
  }
});
```

If the `model` hook resolves the promise before the delay times out then the `LoadingRoute` will not show up at all, which is the behaviour you might want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Coincidence :) I just found a similar solution. Maybe you did not consider the cancel stuff?

Comment: This is great. I'm trying to say 'if loading' show the loading screen for at least 1000' etc so that it doesn't feel clunky - but I also needed something like this to skip the loading if it's really short. : )  @vanthome So, "which one is nicer?"